# How to reference an Imagick object in a PHP UPDATE query?

Tags: php, postgresql, imagemagick, imagick

What is wrong with this query?

Am trying to write an ImageMagick object back into a database (a PostgreSQL bytea field).
This is PHP code - using the Imagick functions.

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET destcol = ".$im." WHERE key = " .$args[0];
```

Comment: and do you have a specific error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're updating string columns without quoting them.;

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET destcol = '".$im."' WHERE key = '" .$args[0]. "'";
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I now at least am able to write something back to data! However, even trying to write the same column back - to a diff column - I can't seem to reproduce the same contents. Yikes! Need help!

Answer (score 1):

If that `$im` is from doing

```
$im = new Imagick();
```

your query will fail. You cannot insert a PHP object into a database like that. At bare mininum, you must do something like

```
$im = new Imagick();
$serialized = serialize($im);
$safe_serialized = mysql_real_escape_string($serialized);

$sql = "INSERT ... destcol='$safe_serialized' ...";
```

Also note that this will most likely fail - if the object is holding open files internally, those file handles will almost certainly not be valid once the object is pulled out of the database and unserialize()'d.

Why do you need to preserve an imagick object in this fashion? The cost of instantiating it in the first place is not exactly high.

Comment: Thanks for this response. Yes, it _is_ from Imagick - you're helping me get closer to a solution. I am working on a PG col, so am using the pg_unescape_bytea version.
From there, I'm working with the unescaped string like this:
$im->readimageblob($imagestring);
Of course, still don't know what success I'm having actually manipulating the graphics, 'cause haven't been able to successfully write it back to data!

Comment: But why store the IM object in the db? There's a case to be made for storing an actual image file in a database, but a PHP object to manipulate that image? Why...?

Comment: The 'why' is more philosophical than practical - for the moment, we want to see what's possible. I have been experimenting with various serialize / pg_escape functions on the string, but can't return it to any usable form - or even any plausible length! Any ideas?